# How to find the basis of vector spaces, and their dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have doubts when calculating the dimension of the following vector spaces and subspaces, since I do not know how I can find a basis for each of them. If you can help me find your bases and dimension I will be very grateful, since I am completely lost.

They are:

1) $C^1[-1,1]$. (Space of continuous and derivable functions only once in the closed interval [-1,1]).

2) $D=\{f \in C^1[-1, 1]:f(x) - xf'(x) = 0\}$. ($D$ is a subspace of 1))

3) $S=\{f \in C^1[-1, 1]:f(-1) =f(1)\}$. ($S$ is a subspace of 1))

Comment: If i recall correctly 1 is infinite dimensional

Comment: Indeed, consider the functions $x^\alpha$ for $1<\alpha<2$.

Comment: @ZelosMalum I also think so, what happens is that I ask since I read in a book that $C^1[-1,1]/S \cong \mathbb {R}$ And I wonder how is this possible?

Comment: The quotient of two infinite dimensional spaces can very well be finite dimensional. The easiest example is $V/V \simeq \{0\}$ for each vector space $V$, also if it is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @LeBtz So you say that the three spaces that I posed in my question are infinite dimensional ?. Could you explain to me why this vector space quotient is finite dimensional?

Comment: When you say "computing the dimension" and answer by infinite dimension, this is a bit misleading. The dimension is a cardinal number and saying infinite may not be precise enough.

Answer (score 2):

$C^1$ does not mean "differentiable function *only* once". It means a function has continuous first derivative. See for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Functional_analysis.

- For the first one, consider the polynomials $p_n(x)=x^n$.
- For the second one, do you know how to solve the differential equation?
- Consider $p_m(x)=x^{2m}$.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I think that for the first space, when considering the function that indicates to me, it would have to be infinite dimensional since it is generated by polynomials of different degree. For the second case, how can I relate this set to the differential equations? I already know that the elements of $D$ are of the form $cx$, with $c$ a real constant. And to conclude with the latter, I think it is infinite dimensional since it is generated by even polynomials. Can you guide me please?

Comment: For (1) and (3), you are right. For (2), it is related to the differential equations because the condition of $f$ *is* a differential equation.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but then D is also infinite dimensional? I find it rather 1-dimensional, since I feel it is the space generated by x? I do not know if I'm right?

Comment: No. The solution space to a differential equation does not need to be infinite dimension. In your case, $D$ is indeed of finite dimension.

Comment: So I'm right in my reasoning? $D$ is 1-dimensional since it is the space generated by $x$?. For example, the function $Cos(x)$ is even, how can I write this function as elements of an $S$ base?

Comment: @DanielaRondón you may not find a basis for the vector space $S$, you know that there exists a basis by the Axiom of Choice. To prove that the vector space is infinite dimensional, all you have to do is show that there is an infinite set of linearly independent functions. Also, you asked how to write $\cos x$ as linear combination of vectors from a basis, and the answer, of course, depends on the basis you chose (since it is not unique)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Seq}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$Judging from the comments, it seems to me that you're struggling not with this particular question, but with some of the underlying ideas.

By way of analogy, consider the vector space $V$ of all real sequences $\Seq{a} = (a_{k})_{k=0}^{\infty}$, and the subspaces

- $D = \{\Seq{a} \in V : \text{$a_{k+1} = a_{k}$ for all $k \geq 0$}\} \subset V$,
- $S = \{\Seq{a} \in V : a_{0} = a_{1}\} \subset V$.

The space $D$, which consists of all constant sequences, is one-dimensional, with the constant sequence $(1, 1, 1, \dots)$ as basis.

Each of the spaces $V$ and $S$ is infinite-dimensional: the infinite, linearly-independent (ordered) set $(\mathbf{e}_{k})_{k=2}^{\infty}$ of "standard basis sequences" is in each of $V$ and $S$.

The quotient $V/S$ is finite-dimensional. To prove this, it suffices to find a finite-dimensional vector space $W$ and *surjective* linear map $\Pi:V \to W$ with $\ker(\Pi) = S$.

Here, a natural approach is to define $\Pi:V \to \Reals$ by $\Pi(\Seq{a}) = a_{0} - a_{1}$. If $a$ is a real number and $\Seq{a} = (a, 0, 0, \dots)$, then $\Pi(\Seq{a}) = a$, so $\Pi$ is surjective. Further, $\Pi(\Seq{a}) = 0$ if and only if $a_{0} - a_{1} = 0$, i.e., $a_{0} = a_{1}$, so $\ker(\Pi) = S$. It follows that, as real vector spaces, $V/S \simeq \Reals$.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but based on your response then to test isomorphisms between vector quotient spaces $V/W$  is enough to find a mapping surjective with kernel $W$, then $V/W \cong K$, K is a field.?

Comment: Not quite: To prove $V/S \simeq W$, it's enough to find a surjective linear map $\Pi:V \to W$ with $\ker(\Pi) = S$. In my example, $W$ is the vector space of real numbers.